# Sqlite.jsm queries

Tags: javascript, sqlite, mozilla

i'm trying to use sqlite.jsm instead of mozStorage .
here my original code (file.sqlite is already open):

```
var sql = "UPDATE row SET color=?1 WHERE id=?2";
  var statement = connection.createAsyncStatement(sql);
  statement.bindInt32Parameter(0, row.color);
  statement.bindInt32Parameter(2, row.id);
  statement.executeAsync();
```

the new code :

```
    Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/Sqlite.jsm");
    Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/Task.jsm");

    Task.spawn(function() {
      var db;
      try {
    // Open a database
    db = yield Sqlite.openConnection({ path: "file.sqlite" });

    var sql = "UPDATE row SET color=?1 WHERE id=?2";
    var dataToInsert = [
      ["color", row.color],
      ["id", row.id],

    for (var data of dataToInsert) {
      yield db.execute(sql, data);
    }

  } catch (ex) {
    // **Here i get :  Error(s) encountered during statement execution.**
  } finally {
    if (db) {
      yield db.close();
    }
  }
});
```

So how to pass parameters on an UPDATE query using sqlite.jsm ?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It's probably late for the one who asked the question, but still may be useful.

Sqlite.jsm encourages using queries with named parameters and objects as parameters storage, so correct code would look like this:

```js
Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/Sqlite.jsm");
Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/Task.jsm");

return Task.spawn(function*() {
    var db;
    try {
        // Open a database
        db = yield Sqlite.openConnection({path: "file.sqlite"});

        var sql = "UPDATE row SET color = :color WHERE id = :id";
        var params = {
            'color': row.color,
            'id': row.id
        };

        return db.execute(sql, params);
    } catch (ex) {
     // Exception handling
    } finally {
        if (db) {
            yield db.close();
        }
    }
});
```